# cocoon gem can't remove nested field image

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, cocoon-gem

I have set up the cocoon gem correctly and everything is working fine, I can upload images as required but when I click remove, it does not seem to remove the image. Here is my code:

_image_fields.html.erb

```
<div class="nested-fields">
  <%= f.text_area :description %>
  <%= f.file_field :picture %>
  <%= link_to_remove_association "remove", f %>
</div>
```

here is my form:

```
<div class="imagefield">
  <h2>Images</h2>
    <h4>upload images</h4>
      <hr>
       <div class="customgap">
         <div class="images">
           <%= f.fields_for :images do |image| %>
             <%= render 'image_fields', f: image  %>
           <% end %>
          <div class="links">
            <%= link_to_add_association 'add image', f, :images %>
          </div>
         </div>
       </div>
     </div>
```

in controller:

```
images_attributes: [:id, :description, :picture, :_destroy]
```

Image model

```
class Image < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_attached_file :picture, styles: { medium: "300x300>", thumb: "100x100>" }
  validates_attachment_content_type :picture, content_type: /\Aimage\/.*\Z/
end
```

Comment: When you click remove for an image, ultimately a param gets posted named _destroy, so in your controller's strong params, do you have :_destroy included as a whitelisted param for images_attributes?

Comment: @hypern I have the images_attributes

Comment: I see no immediate mistake, can you see an error in the rails logfile (`log/development.log`) ? Otherwise it could help to show us what is posted to the controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to  `:allow_destroy => true` in the controller

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :images, :allow_destroy => true
```